# Laguerre polynomials and Gram Schmidt

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials

Last two days I was trying to solve the following problem But I couldn't.
It's a problem (#5.2.2) from **Mathematical Methods for Physicists** by **George B. Arfken and Hans J. Weber**, *7th Edition*.

I tried to look for the solution in the Solution Manual [here](http://www.slideshare.net/nadeemashraf986/copy-of-arfken-solution) but it just doesn't explain the solution completely and has nothing mentioned but the actual answers. I'm looking for the complete procedure that gets us to answers.

Thanks.

---

Here's the problem:

***Apply the Gram-Schmidt procedure to form the first three Laguerre polynomials:***

**${u_{n} (x) = x^n ,\qquad  n=0,1,2,...,\qquad 0\le x< \infty, \qquad   w(x)=e^{-x}}$**

The conventional normalization is:
$$\int_0^\infty L_m(x)L_n(x)e^{-x}\,dx=\delta_{mn}.$$

The answers are:

$${L_0=1,\qquad L_1=(1-x),\qquad L_2=\frac{2-4x+x^2}{2} }$$

Comment: If memory serves, Arfken and Weber at the very least described the algorithm for performing Gram-Schmidt. Did you try plugging things in the appropriate places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We apply the Gram Schmidt orthogonalization procedure to
$$ P_1(x)=c \qquad P_2(x)=ax \qquad P_3(x)=bx^2$$

1) Take $P_1$ and normalize it

$$ ||P_1(x)||^2=\int_0^{\infty}c^2e^{-x}=c^2 $$

So $c=1 $ and $L_0=1 $

2) Take $P_2$ and subtract to it its projection on $L_0$, then normalize the result

$$P_{2|L_0} = \int_0^{\infty} (ax)e^{-x}dx =a   \\P_2-P_{2|L_0}=a(x-1) \\
||P_2-P_{2|L_0}||^2 = \int_0^{\infty} a^2(x-1)^2e^{-x}=a^2$$

Now we are free to choose either $ a=1$ or $a=-1 $ , to remain consistent with your notation we choose the latter and get

$$L_1=1-x$$

3)Take $P_3$ and subtract to it its projection on $L_0$ and on $L_1$ then normalize it and get $L_2$ with very analogous procedure