# Find the first $3$ orthogonal polynomials of Laguerre (in relation to $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^{\infty} f(x)g(x)e^{-x}\ dx$)

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Find the first $3$ orthogonal polynomials of Laguerre (in relation to
>    $\langle f,g\rangle  = \int_0^{\infty} f(x)g(x)e^{-x}\ dx$)

I don't know which definition I should use for the Laguerre polynomials and if my definition generate orthogonal polynomials.

I've found this recursive definition:

$$L_0 = 1, L_1 = 1-x\\ $$

$$ L_{k+1}(x)=\frac{(2k+1-x)L_{k}(x)-kL_{k-1}(x)}{k+1}$$

So I can easily get the third one. However I don't know if these polynomials are orthogonal because the wikipedia article mentions that the **generalized** Laguerre polynomials are orthogonal and I don't think these are generalized. Also, I didn't use the dot product from the exercise. So I guess my way is not what my teacher intended for me to do.

Comment: Maybe relevant: [Gaussian_quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature). Also, in the intro of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials), it does say they are orthogonal. But I guess you are asked to do the derivation yourself, say using [Gram–Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Comment: There are (at least) two relevant math.SE precursors: 
[Orthogonal polynomials and Gram Schmidt](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299119/316749) (6y 2m old) and  [Laguerre polynomials and 
Gram Schmidt](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1787902/316749) (2y 11m old). Cf also the notes on [Orthogonal polynomials](https://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/orthopoly.pdf), page 7, and pp 10-13 .

Comment: *Generalised Laguerre polynomials* $L_n^{(\alpha)}$ arise when starting (Gram-Schmidt) with the scalar product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^{\infty} f(x)g(x)e^{-x}x^\alpha\ dx$, where $\alpha > -1$ is a parameter. Thus $L_n\equiv L_n^{(0)}$  are the Laguerre polynomials.